# \pstilt doesn't work

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

My ultimate aim is to produce a coordinate system whose axes aren't orthogonal. I came open instructions telling me to use \pstilt in order to do so.
I wanted to start by simply tilting the text and although, I don't get an error message I don't get a tilted text either.

Here is a minimal (not) working example:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\pstilt{45}{Texte 1}

\end{document}
```

I work with Texshop (Version 4.44) on a Macbook running macOS Catalina Version 10.15.3.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: PSTricks has a couple of restrictions. With Ti*k*Z and its 3d library it is trivial to project text on a plane.

Comment: You need to compile using latex+dvips not pdflatex. Add `% !TEX TS-program = latex` at the top of your file.

Comment: @ Alan Munn this seems to do the trick! Thank you very much!